# Ironpython - Named parameters to constructor

Tags: .net, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

When I create an instance of my C# class in IronPython with named parameters to the constructor, it is setting properties corresponding to the names of the parameters.  I wish to disable this behavior so I can have better control on the order the properties are evaluated.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to turn this off without modifying IronPython.