# NHibernate: cannot call QueryOver<T>().List() from IronPython

Tags: nhibernate, ironpython

I'm working on a project that uses NHibernate and also IronPython.

So from IronPython, I can query single instances of `class Foo` fine. When I want a list of all instances of `class Foo` from C#, I would just do

```
session.QueryOver<Foo>().List()
```

but when I try to translate that to python,

```
session.QueryOver[Foo]().List()
```

I always get an exception

```
System.MissingMemberException: 'QueryOver[Foo, Foo]' object has no attribute 'List'
```

At first I thought it was a problem with default-parameters to `QueryOver`, but `ISession` actually has 4 overloads for `QueryOver` - none of them have default-parameters (I still had tried passing Missing.Value as in [Can I use Named and Optional Arguments in ironpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384989/can-i-use-named-and-optional-arguments-in-ironpython) before, which didn't help)

Then I thought List() might be an extension-method, but I tried `clr.ImportExtensions` like in https://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/accessing-my-extension-methods-from-python-component which did nothing.

`QueryOver[Foo,Foo]` is derived from `QueryOver[Foo]`. Now looking at https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/QueryOver.cs#L223 I see that `QueryOver<Foo>` does have a method `List()`, but it is defined in a weird way.

I think that method just explicitly says which `List()` method from the interfaces it implements, so I absolutely don't understand what is going on here.

Can someone shed some light on this issue? I'm getting desperate.

Comment: indeed, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation says that the "weird" definition explicitly selects which interface's method it implements. It also says that the class doesn't actually have the method - you need to upcast the object to select the interface-method you use.

unfortunately, upcasting doesn't seem to exist in python(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out:

The "weird" definition in https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/QueryOver.cs#L223 is an explicitly implemented interface-method. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation such methods don't actually become members of the objects (IMHO this is extremely counter-intuitive - you have an object that implements an interface but then doesn't have a method from that interface!?). This is why IronPython can't find the method - C# apparently resolves the call differently.

Anyways - according to http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dark-corners.shtml#interfaces you need to call such methods differently in python. You need to explicitly select the interface you use like this:

```
IQueryOver[Foo].List(session.QueryOver[Foo]())
```

Honestly, I don't see why the question gets downvoted. IMHO this is a relatively reasonable use-case (given that NHibernate and IronPython are both popular libraries) and IMHO it's surprising that it doesn't work the way I first tried.
I tried several things to solve the problem myself before asking - and to finally solve it, I had to go through the NHibernate sources, GUESS what that definition does (because it's rather exotic and not well documented IMHO) and then find how you can get python to handle a case that it should be able to handle on its own.